# Get value of Trend line like you do with SMA in PIne Script TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I wanted to program algorithm using a trend line. It might not as simple as just crossover moving average, but as an example:

you can code crossover a SMA line like this:

```
crossover(close, sma(close, 50))
```

but how can I code crossover a trend line?

```
lineInstance = .. // define a trend line 
crossover(close, lineInstance)
crossover(close[1], lineInstance[1])

.. and more tricky algorithm using the trend line instance
```

Is this not possible, or do you have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: See the answer to this question. The idea is the same. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485205/three-moving-average-cross-over-in-trading-view-using-pine-script-version-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485205/three-moving-average-cross-over-in-trading-view-using-pine-script-version-4)

Comment: See the answer to this question. The idea is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485205/three-moving-average-cross-over-in-trading-view-using-pine-script-version-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `line.new` function to define the `lineInstance` variable?
If yes, you can use `line.get_price(id, x)` function to get the current y-value of the line object, and then pass it to `crossover` function.

```
currentLineValue = line.get_price(lineInstance, 0)
priceCrossUpLine = crossover(close, currentLineValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be worked. I encountered an another issue relating to this issue so if you don't mind I appreciate your help there too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510011/n-a-value-when-line-new-with-if-statement-in-pine-script-tradingview