# n/a value when line.new with if statement in Pine Script TradingView

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I wanted to create an indicator that shows when a close crossed over a trend line.

Here's the code,
here "trendLineCrossover" should show 1.00 on crossover bar and 0.00 on other bars. But actually this shows me 0.00 only on the last bar (and the consecutive area) and on other bars it shows n/a .

```
lineObj = if (syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:SRMUSDT")
    if (barstate.islast)
        line.new(x1=3380-89, y1=0.9609, x2=3380 , y2=1.0216)

line.set_extend(id=lineObj, extend=extend.right)
trendLine = line.get_price(lineObj, 0)

trendLineCrossover = crossover(close, trendLine)
plotshape(trendLineCrossover, title="trendLineCrossover", color=color.purple, style=shape.xcross)
```

How can I fix the code to show the expected result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we draw your line on the `x2` bar no 3380 and include `barstate.islast` in conditions evaluated on every bar, as enclosing your line drawing call inside the `if` block will not make the detection of crossovers possible:

#### Version 1

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true, max_bars_back = 5000)
var line lineObj = na
trendLineCrossover = false
if (syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:SRMUSDT") and bar_index == 3380
    lineObj := line.new(x1=bar_index-89, y1=0.9609, x2=bar_index , y2=1.0216, extend=extend.right)
        
trendLine = line.get_price(lineObj, bar_index)
trendLineCrossover := barstate.islast and crossover(close, trendLine)
plotshape(trendLineCrossover, title="trendLineCrossover", color=color.purple, style=shape.xcross)

// For validation only.
c = close < trendLine
plotchar(c, "c", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)

// Show bg starting at the bar where we draw our line.
bgcolor(bar_index > 3380-89 ? color.silver : na)
```

[image]

#### Version 2

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
var line lineObj = na
if (syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:SRMUSDT") and bar_index == 3380
    lineObj := line.new(x1=bar_index-89, y1=0.9609, x2=bar_index , y2=1.0216, extend=extend.right)
        
trendLine = line.get_price(lineObj, bar_index)
trendLineCrossover = crossover(close, trendLine)
plotshape(trendLineCrossover, title="trendLineCrossover", color=color.purple, style=shape.xcross)

// —————— For validation only.
// Bar no.
plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// Plots the value returned by line.get_price() so you can see when it becomes available.
plot(trendLine, "trendLine", color.blue, 6, transp = 60)
// Show bg starting at the bar where where the line is drawn.
bgcolor(bar_index > 3380 ? color.silver : na)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @pinecoders-lucf, this should be worked, but on the chart, 27 Dec 23:00 on 1h BINANCE:SRMUSDT, this is actually crossing over the trend line, as you can see as well, but "trendLineCrossover" showing me 0 on the bar. would you explain me why this happens?

Comment: That's because your `trendLineCrossover ` variable includes `barstate.islast` in its requirements to be true, so only crosses occurring in the dataset's last bar will be detected. You can try removing `barstate.islast` and see if you like your script better that way.

Comment: thansk @pinecoders-lucf , but I changed the line to `trendLineCrossover := crossover(close, trendLine)` but now I can only see 0 on bar_index == 3380 (and latter ones) and n/a for previous ones including the over crossing bar. sorry perhaps my side's problem? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I put up a v2. Streamlined some things but added some debugging plots to help show you what's going on. Keep in mind that when you draw the line, you start it 89 bars back, so while there's a line on the previous 89 bars at that point, `line.get_price()` cannot return a value there because the line didn't exist when the script calculated on those bars. The silver bg now only starts when you draw the line, rather than from the beginning of the line.

Comment: thanks @pinecoders-lucf, I understand that and solved my issue. `plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)` and `bgcolor(trendLine ? color.silver : na)` helped me a lot. So basically, drawn trend line can be accessible for forward bars but not for backward bars, yes? I found this a little complex but anyhow solved, thans again.

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct. To make it easier, it helps to picture your script executing from bar to bar, starting from the left. See the usrman page on the [Execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) for a more complete explanation of Pine's runtime environment. For other debugging tips like using `plotchar()`, see the usrman page on [Debugging](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html).